# C++ template argument of unknown type

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we want to write a function which is supposed to get a value as a template parameter (for, say, efficiency reasons), but we don't know in advance the type of the parameter we're expecting. It is possible to implement it as

```
template<typename T, T val>
func() { cout << val; }
```

However, it is not fun to call such a function

```
func<int, 5>()
```

is it possible to rewrite func s.t. we can call it in the following way?

```
func<5>()
```

Comment: Might work with the `auto` type.

Comment: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html

Comment: Why not `template<typename T> constexpr void func(T val) { }` and call it as `f(5)`?

Comment: You do know that `template` types can only be simple types, like `int` and `bool`. You can't put a `double`, for example, instead of that `int`, right? So I'm wondering whether it's ever useful to do this.

Comment: How about `template<typename T, T val>
func(std::integral_constant<T, val>) { cout << val; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that mostly depends on your actual function is to define it as it follows:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void func(T val) { }
```

Then invoke it as `f(5)` and have the template parameter deduced from the parameter of the function itself.

Otherwise, in C++14, you cannot avoid using the pattern `template<typename T, T value>`.
It is the same pattern used by the Standard Template Library, see as an example the definition of `std::integral_constant`.

A possible solution that mitigates (maybe) the boilerplate is based on the use of a struct, as an example:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    template<T value>
    static void func() {}
};
```

You can the do something like this:

```
using IntS = S<int>;
// ....
IntS::func<5>();
```

With the upcoming revision C++17, you will manage to do it as it follows:

```
template<auto value>
void func() {}
```

This can be invoked as `f<5>()`, that is what you are looking for..